# Can a site user pass their own arguments to model functions?

Tags: php, security, codeigniter, session

Are functions inside of models directly accessible by users?
**Can a user pass arguments directly to a function in a model?** Or, do arguments have to be passed through php?

*In otherwords:*
I have a model called notifications and in there a function called `get_notifs($user)`... I use the controller to call the function like  the `get_notifs($_SESSION['user_id'])` (which is encrypted). I don't want someone to be able to call `get_notifs()` with anything but their $_session as a argument. What is the best solution?

- Am I already okay?
- Should I rename `get_notifs()` to
  `_get_notifs()`?
- Should I check the
  `$_SESSION['user_id']` in the method
  itself?
- Or, is there another better solution

  ### than any of these?

I have a controller: ajax.php which loads the model notification

```
    function __construct()
        {
        parent::__construct();
            $this->load->helper('url');
            $this->load->library('tank_auth');
            $this->load->model('notification');
            $this->load->model('search');
        }
function get_notifs()
    {
    $me = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
    if ($e = $this->notification->get_notif($me))
    {
 ...........
    }           
    else{
        echo "nothing was found wtf?";
    }
```

.........................................................
model: notification.php

```
function get_notifs($user){
......
}
```

Comment: these are not functions there methods, please try not to confuse them.

Comment: show the structure of your model and how these functions are related

Comment: Using the $_SESSION function is not taking advantage of the great session class inside codeigniter. Check it out..

Comment: I gave you guys some more info to work with... maybe it was stupid i have to get_notifs() functions but the one I worry about is the one that accepts a param.. I just don't want hackers to be able to directly insert a param into my model get_notifs($user) function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Your code is perfectly fine!

- Am I already okay?

  - I Think so
- Should I rename `get_notifs()` to `_get_notifs()`?

  - No, it's a public method so no need to make it look private.
- Should I check the `$_SESSION['user_id']` in the method itself?

  - No, this is the controller's job
- Or, is there another better solution than any of these?

  - You only need a solution to a problem, and i don't see a problem here

it sounds liek your application may be used by people other then yourself, i.e the public developers, why would you want enforce developers to code things your way, that's going to make them upset at your application.

CI Only routes requests to a controller, the user cannot access a model or library or any other class, the route goes like so: `/controller/method/param`

the first segment will only ever load a controller file, the second will call the method in the param, passing any other variables such as param to that method.
[image]
Source: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/appflow.html

As you can see from the flow chart above, only the controller has access to the model's

Comment: So no user can just call like http://BASEURL/models/get_notifs/13 and then get the notifications of a user with ID 13?... I know with CI users can directly pass params to functions in controllers, but is the same not true of functions in models?

Comment: no, because `get_notifs()` does not allow the third parameter in the controller, CI does not route to the models, only the controller, the url you said would mean that you would have to have a controller called models.

Comment: okay I think I get it: because CI doesn't route to models, there's no way for someone to pass an argument to models?.... so are private functions (i.e. `_get_notifs()`) only ever used in controllers? sorry for such newbie questions

Comment: no problem, i have updated my answer to explain a little further any way.

Answer (score 0):

If you'll only use it while in a session the best way would be this:

```
function get_notifs(){
    if(!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
        return false;
    }

    $user = $_SESSION['user_id'];

    /* Your code here */
}
```

There's no point of requiring an argument when you'll only use the function with one specific variable which is also available globaly.

Edit: I don't know why you're using functions in your models. Doesn't make any sense, do you mean methods?

Comment: regarding your edit, I don't know.. I thought I was doing the proper practice. I am getting the params from the controller and then want to pass it to the model to connect to the database.